# Python: functions with loops

Tags: python

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):

    if num_cycles < 1:
        print("Too few.")
    
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print("Too many.")
        
    else:
        for a in num_cycles:
            print(num_cycles,": Lather and rinse.")
          
    print("Done.")
    
    return shampoo_instructions(num_cycles)

shampoo_instructions(2)
```

The error with this code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in 
    shampoo_instructions(2)
  File "main.py", line 11, in shampoo_instructions
    for a in num_cycles:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If anyone knows what I did wrong I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I think you want `for a in range(num_cycles):`.

Comment: But note that your function calls itself recursively with the same argument, so it's never going to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing recursion and iteration. 
You will gain an endless loop!

Also, you can not do

```
for a in b:
```

if both are integer. You have to use

```
for a in xrange(0, b):
```

to iterate over b. 
Most people don't care whether they use xrange or range, but for loops, xrange is slightly faster.

Here your Solution.

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):

    if num_cycles < 1:
        print("Too few.")

    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print("Too many.")

    else:
        for a in xrange(0, num_cycles):
            print(num_cycles,": Lather and rinse.")

    print("Done.")


shampoo_instructions(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for a in num_cycles:` doesn't work because `num_cycles` is a number and there is nothing for the `for` loop to iterate through. `range(num_cycles)` will change from the `num_cycles` to a list of [ 0, 1, ... num_cycles ] which the `for` loop can iterate through.

As @smarx stated, you'll want to remove the line:

```
return shampoo_instructions(num_cycles)
```

This is because you wrote a recursive function where it will keep calling itself over an over.